# New Tag Wiki - approval critera

Tags: discussion, tags

When a new tag wiki is created and getting approved should it be approved it is just stating the name of the game and the manufacture? It seems that the wiki and excerpt should have more information then a statement of which game it should be used for.

https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/19528

[pandemic-iberia](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandemic-iberia)

Excerpt

> Use for questions specific the new game from ZMan games, Pandemic Iberia.

Tag

> Use for questions specific the new game from ZMan games, Pandemic Iberia.
>
> - [ZMan Games](https://www.zmangames.com/en/products/pandemic-iberia/)
> - [Official Rules](https://images-cdn.zmangames.com/us-east-1/filer_public/c3/62/c362beb7-bb07-4834-92f9-693de3f4eda5/zm7120_pandemic_iberia_rules.pdf)
> - [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FG96NBY)
> - [BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/198928/pandemic-iberia)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we should approve that.

Sure, the information is minimal. If you think we should have more, revise the tag wiki and add it. However, "minimal information" is a whole lot better than "no tag wiki excerpt or usage guidance whatsoever", including because [having a tag wiki prevents tags from being deleted if they are only on one question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki) (which is the case for a lot of tags for a long while).

Comment: is a tag that defines itself as itself actually providing any usage information? If someone is going to make a tag it doesn't take much work to add a little information about the game, which in this case could as simple as it is a co-op game where players are trying to prevent plagues from destroying the world.

Comment: Clarifying the publisher and date (in this case "new"... which will probably need changing one day) is usage information, albeit minimal. I'd decline that wiki excerpt as useless if it just said "use for games about pandemic iberia", but it says more than that, which is good. Usually I do like to summarise what the game *is* essentially, but that's something to prompt revision.

Comment: @JoeW Stating the name of the game can also be useful since we have some games where the tag doesn't match the name of the game exactly due to length (and possibly other reasons), though that reason doesn't apply in this specific case

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking at there is the tag wiki *excerpt*. This is the description that shows up when you are adding tags to a question. It should be short, and its primary purpose is to indicate how the tag should be used.

Comment: I added more info and I still question that just putting the games name, publisher and some links in the wiki is not enough information for a tag to be added. There should be at least some basic information about the game in them.

Comment: @JoeW We're not trying to recreate Wikipedia (or BoardGameGeek) in tag wikis. The most important thing is that we can tell how to use the tag, which in most cases means clearly referring to as specific game. Sometimes it can indeed be helpful to add more details, but that doesn't mean (as doppelgreener said) that the basic description shouldn't be approved.

Comment: @Jefromi I guess my point would be what is the point what is the point of a tag wiki if you still have to google the tag for basic info about the game?

Comment: The general expectation is that people are asking questions about games that they have at least a passing familiarity with. The game name and publisher should provide enough information to determine whether the tag matches the topic of the question. If you have to do further research, it probably indicates that that's not the game you're asking about.

Comment: @JoeW To make sure that we know exactly what game it refers to (you never know when there's going to turn out to be some weird naming thing), to provide information about how to use the tag (usually a nonissue, but when there's overlap, sets of games, etc, can be helpful) or how to ask questions about it (also usually a nonissue, but sometimes helpful for FAQ, formatting issues, etc), and perhaps a link to find more information if we want to be helpful. Again, we're not trying to build a new repository of information about games.

Comment: The most relevant comparison on Stack Exchange would be the tags on Sports SE. Tag excerpts regularly state exactly the name of the sport, any common other names, possibly clarification (e.g. the variant or disambiguation from sports of similar names - compare with tags for expansions) and key usage guidelines (e.g. some tags must include a specific sport tag alongside them, others must include a country tag). These never and should not include a history or an encyclopaedic description of the thing they tag for. That is where the full tag wiki comes in, but even then.